# gluLookAt outside display function

Tags: opengl, camera

I'm trying to display a teapot with mouse rotation using GLUT

If placing gluLookAt in display function the teapot get rendered

```
void displayPot()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(              // set up the camera
    0.0, 0.0, 5.0,      // eye position
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,      // lookat position
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0);     // up direction

glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);    // specify object color
glColor3f(1.0, 0.1, 0.1);       // redish
glutSolidTeapot(1);

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

But if i place it in my init function the teapot disappear

```
bool init()
{
glClearColor(0.93f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 100);  // setup a perspective projection

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(              // set up the camera
    0.0, 0.0, 5.0,      // eye position
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,      // lookat position
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0);     // up direction

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);      // enable lighting
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);        // enable

float lpos[] = { 5, 5, 5, 0 };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lpos);

//glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);        // flat shading
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);        // smooth shading

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glClearDepth(1.0f);

return true;
}
```

What's the thing I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the thing I'm doing wrong here?

You're placing it in the init function. That's what wrong.

OpenGL is a state machine and depending on what else is living in your program may alter the state in ways that will later trip you up. For example you or some library (accidently) clear the modelview matrix (or the projection matrix or something else).

As a general rule with OpenGL except for a few outliers, **all** function calls prefixed *gl…* and *glu…* should go into the drawing code, because *it is* drawing code. That included things like *glViewport* and other things that one naively may interpret at "initilaization code".